# Heap buffer overflow caused by single line

Tags: c, for-loop, malloc, c-strings, function-definition

Currently trying to work on my C (very new to it) by doing some leetcode questions. I'm puzzled by this issue, as it gives me a heap buffer overflow but only because of a single line. `interpret()` is called and passed a string `command` where `1 <= command.length <= 100`, and will consist of `"G"`, `"()"`, and/or `"(al)"` in some order, with no other characters appearing.

```
char * interpret(char * command){
    
    char * ret = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(command) - 1; i++)
    {
        if(command[i] == 'G')
        {
            ret[counter] = 'G';
            counter ++;
        }
        else if(command[i] == '(')
        {
            if (command[i + 1] == ')')
            {
                ret[counter] = 'o';
                counter ++;
            }
            else
            {
                //ret[counter] = 'a'; ***********
                ret[counter + 1] = 'l';
                counter += 2;
            }
        }
        ret[counter] = '\0';
    }
    return realloc(ret, counter * sizeof(char));
}
```

If the starred line is uncommented, then the entire program crashes in leetcode, but works fine on VSCode and returns the correct solution. I would appreciate any help, I'm sure it's something small I'm missing. Thanks.

ETA: [Here is the leetcode problem in question](https://leetcode.com/problems/goal-parser-interpretation/)

Comment: Also `sizeof(command)` is not not not what you want.

Comment: @steve command is the string that is passed in by leetcode. What should I be using instead of sizeof?

Comment: @vito: `strlen(command)`, assuming it's a NUL-terminated C-style string. `sizeof(command)` will always return the size of a char pointer (typically four bytes on 32 bit systems, eight bytes on 64 bit systems), regardless of the amount of data it's pointing to.

Comment: @steve thank you for the explanation. I changed the for loop to use `sizeof(command)` instead but it is still giving me the same error as before.

Comment: @vito You understand now why `sizeof(command)` is wrong and won't work and must be changed to something else, right?

Comment: Note that using `sizeof(char)` is redundant, as the standard defines this to be 1 always.

Comment: @steve yes you explained it well, it takes the size of the pointer itself rather than the array it points to, whereas `strlen` actually takes the size of the array and therefore the null-terminated string.

Comment: @paddy yes thank you, I'm just trying to stay in the habit of making sure I multiply the size of what's in the array by the length of it so I don't run into issues with ints or other types in the future.

Comment: @vito I recommend you append how `interpret()` is called.  Even better, a [mcve].

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I went ahead and added that at the beginning

Comment: @vito "interpret() is called and passed a string command ..." _describes_ code.  True code is better as the description lacks important details.  Consider a [mcve].  Also note that `malloc(sizeof(char) * 100)` is one too small for a string of length 100 as suggested by "1 <= command.length <= 100".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pass the size of command to interpret.**

In C, when you pass a string to a function, you’re not actually passing the full string, you’re passing a pointer to the first element in the string. This becomes an issue when you do sizeof(command), as you're just getting the size of the pointer and not the full string. If you try to loop over this string as done in the question, this can either lead to an underread, if you have a string longer than `sizeof(char*)`, or a buffer overflow, if you have a string shorter than `sizeof(char*)`. Generally, you shouldn’t use sizeof on pointers.

To fix your code, use `strlen` on the string you're passing to `command` in the calling function and do something similar to this:

```
char * interpret(char * command, int size){

char * ret = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
int counter = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
{ ...
```

Comment: Using `sizeof(command)` along with moving the `ret[counter] = 0` outside of the for loop fixed the problem. neither solution worked independently but together it did. Thank you both @fosstar @Vlad from Moscow

Comment: @vito If you're still using `sizeof(command)`, your code is still badly broken.

Comment: 2nding Steve's post here. please in the future replace any ```sizeof``` calls on string pointers with ```strlen``` It'll save you a lot of problems in the future.

Comment: @steve @fosstar I am stupid and mistyped, yes I meant to say I changed it to `strlen(command)` and it worked, `sizeof` was breaking it. It won't let me edit the comment for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

The parameter `command` has the pointer type `char *`.

So the operator `sizeof` applied to the pointer yields the size of the pointer instead of the length of the pointed string

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(command) - 1; i++)
```

You could just write

```
for( size_t i = 0; command[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

Also it is unclear why there is used the magic number 100

```
char * ret = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
```

You could at first count the result characters and then allocated an array of the appropriate size and fill it.

Moreover due to this statement

```
    ret[counter] = '\0';
```

(that is also unclear why it is within the for loop) you need to allocate an array with `counter + 1` characters instead of `counter` characters as you are doing

```
return realloc(ret, counter * sizeof(char));
```

A straightforward approach can look the following way as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * interpret( const char *command )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; command[i] != '\0';  )
    {
        if ( command[i] == 'G' )
        {
            ++n;
            ++i;
        }
        else if ( strncmp( command + i, "()", 2 ) == 0 )
        {
            ++n;
            i += 2;
        }
        else if (  strncmp( command + i, "(al)", 4 ) == 0 )
        {
            n += 2;
            i += 4;
        }
        else
        {
            ++i;
        }
    }

    char *result = malloc( n + 1 );

    if ( result != NULL )
    {
        n = 0;

        for ( size_t i = 0; command[i] != '\0';  )
        {
            if ( command[i] == 'G' )
            {
                result[n++] = 'G';
                ++i;
            }
            else if ( strncmp( command + i, "()", 2 ) == 0 )
            {
                result[n++] = 'o';
                i += 2;
            }
            else if (  strncmp( command + i, "(al)", 4 ) == 0 )
            {
                result[n++] = 'a';
                result[n++] = 'l';
                i += 4;
            }
            else
            {
                ++i;
            }
        }

        result[n] = '\0';
    }

    return result;
}

int main( void )
{
    char *s = interpret( "G()(al)" );
    if ( s ) puts( s );
    free( s );

    s = interpret( "(al)G(al)()()G" );
    if ( s ) puts( s );
    free( s );
}
```

The program output is

```
Goal
alGalooG
```

Comment: This suggestion no longer throws an error, but now the script only returns null, instead of the "Go" I was getting before

Comment: As for the 100 number, that is the max length possible given by leetcode in the restrictions. I originally had it to `sizeof(char) * sizeof(command)` and only changed it when trying to fix my issue. The `ret[counter]` portion is inside the for loop to set the last value to null, since when I didn't have that, I was getting odd characters after the word, which given input "G()(al)" should be "Goal".

Comment: @vito This statement ret[counter] = '\0'; shall not be within the for loop.